# How to check if two unsorted lists are equal in Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, collections, stream

Need to compare two lists.
Lists can contain null and duplicate(Object::equals) items.

{4, 100, 100} equals {100, 4, 100}

{4, 100, 100} not equals {100, 4, 4}

{"W", "s", "s", null, null} equals {null, "s", null, "s", "W"}

method:

```
BiPredicate<List<?>, List<?>> compareList = (a, b) -> ???;
```

tests:

```
List<String> listS = Arrays.asList("W", "s", "s", null, null);
List<String> listT = Arrays.asList(null, "s", null, "s", "W");

assertTrue(compareList.test(listS, listT));

List<Integer> listA = Arrays.asList(4, 100, 100);
List<Integer> listB = Arrays.asList(100, 4, 100);
List<Integer> listC = Arrays.asList(100, 4, 4);

assertTrue(compareList.test(listA, listB));
assertFalse(compareList.test(listA, listC));
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to make that clear—not put it in the comments. Currently, you just dumped some code that we can only presume doesn't work. Explain what your code is supposed to be doing, the actual results, and how the results don't fit your expectations. Try including a [mcve]. How are you defining equality? How do you handle duplicate elements?

Comment: Why are you asking when you already have solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.containsInAnyOrder()` to check the list contains as below

```
assertThat("List equality without order", 
            listA, containsInAnyOrder(listB.toArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [AssertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) and [`containsExactlyInAnyOrder()`](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/ListAssert.html#containsExactlyInAnyOrder(ELEMENT...))

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(null, "s", null, "s", "W");
assertThat(list).containsExactlyInAnyOrder("W", "s", "s", null, null);
```

There is no need to write your own assertion library for basic Java types. There are already a few: AssertJ, Hamcrest, etc.

Comment: I may need to solve the same task, but not in the test, without test framework.